# How to display day label if there is only one data point in flot?

Tags: javascript, flot

Following is my `xaxis` parameter for flot -

```
xaxis: {
    mode : "time",
    minTickSize: [1, "day"],
    color : "#999"
}
```

What I want is that day labels be visible on the x-axis. It works when I have more than one data point as in here -

[image: Flot working perfectly]

But it doesn't work when I've only one data point.

[image: Flot day label not working.]

Is there anyway to render the day label when there is only one data point? I tried using 
"1 hour" as the minimum tick size and it clutters the timeline.

Comment: Can you post your data? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: It is not working for two data points as well if they are close enough. Here's the data from one sample - 

`[ 1353313709000,  154], [ 1353313448000,  154]]`

Comment: I would setup graphing options (radio buttons) to allow the user to refresh the view to monthly, weekly, daily or hourly breakdown.

Comment: @ApoorvParijat Did you manage to fix that problem? I'm having it as well.

Comment: I'm moved to using highstock. Here's the highstock options that worked for me - https://gist.github.com/apoorvparijat/9599474

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a single day I created. I don't think there should be any issue.
[image]